# Properly translate an error that is using logger to a regular string

Tags: java, exception, slf4j

I currently have something like this:

```
public T onInterruptedException(Exception e){
    logger.error("Error: ", e);
}
```

I was wondering there was any way to convert the exception to a string with it keeping the "level" (like this one is a error level). I thought of something like converting the exception to a string such as:

```
String thisException = e.toString();
```

But I do not know what good this will be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Do that. That is what we all do.

You can also use `e.getMessage()` if you want a more human printed message.

```
public T onInterruptedException(Exception e){
    logger.error(e.toString());
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: can I still do that without having the *logger.error* ?